# Applescript: Close Word document? (Office 2011)

Tags: ms-word, applescript, ms-office

i'm simply trying to close a document (without quitting word), but this does not work.

I've tried :

```
close documents saving no
close active document
close document 1
```

but none of this is working..

The error I get (on the close line) is:

```
Microsoft Word got an error: The object you are trying to access does not exist
```

Here is a simplified script. Anyone have any ideas? All examples online seem to use this syntax, not sure if anything changed in the mac office 2011 version?

```
set input to {POSIX path of "/Users/Wesley/Desktop/test.doc"}


--ENABLE GUI SCRIPTING
tell application "System Events"
if UI elements enabled is false then set UI elements enabled to true
end tell

--RUN THE GUISCRIPT
set pdfSavePath to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "Set destination folder")
repeat with x in input
display dialog x

tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    open x
    set theActiveDoc to the active document

    close theActiveDoc saving no

    return
    end tell
 end repeat
```

Comment: I would try it with the repeat routine in the tell statement (after the activate statement). May be that has an effect.

Comment: @DigiMonk I have removed the repeat entirely, no effect. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

close active document and close document 1 both work for me.  Perhaps you need a delay statement before the theActiveDoc variable is assigned?

Comment: Just tried that (added a delay of 5 seconds, but no difference). What version of office are you using? (Home / student / pro)

Comment: 2011 14.2.5  Have you tried running the close statements by themselves?

Comment: Just updated  to that same version, but no change. This on a new imac. What do you mean by running the close statements by themselves? I do need to have a document open first don't I?

Comment: close active document does nothing (no error, no close). close documents doesn't work (error), close document 1 doesn't work (error).

Comment: Well, never mind, I reinstalled Office and it works now. Perhaps I didn't install the Automator actions. Thank you anyway for your time!